# How can I distribute royalties to addresses with an ERC721

Tags: solidity, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets

I was thinking about a use case let's say that we have a deployed smart contract ERC721 with 100 NFTS all of them minted. and I want to send to these 100 addresses royalties?

How can approach that? should I use PaymentSplitter?

Can you share please any resources or an example of a smart contract that can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it manually, by creating a batch transfer kind of function that looks like this:
`function sendRoyalties(address[] calldata _nftHolders, uint amountToSend) external;`

or you can create a Custom Method:

1. You can create a custom contract where all the royalties will be sent.
2. You should then implement a function that allows anyone that has an NFT to `claimRoyalties()`
3. this function will check if the user has an NFT from your collection, will
   send the royalties and update (ideally a mapping) its claimable Royalties so that they can no longer claim or whatever conditions you want.

It should check if the caller has an NFT, and under the hood:

- it should then update a `mapping(uint => uint)` for `tokenId => amountClaimed`
  Example: 100 ETH royalties `100 / 100 = 1 ETH`

UserA holder of **TokenID "99"** claims **1 ETH**

mapping is equal to `(99 => 1 ETH);`

- after a while 100 more ETH are added to the smart contract
- UserB holder of **TokenID 11**, can claim `(200 / 100) = 2 ETH`
- UserA holder of TokenID 99 can claim `(200 / 100) = 2 ETH - 1 ETH` (already claimed and visible on mapping)

`claimableRoyalties[99] == 1 ETH`, before the claim

`claimableRoyalties[99] == 2 ETH`, after the claim

Comment: Can you please demonstrate with a custom smart contract with a Claimroyalties() function for more details?

Comment: haha I would love to, but it's a job in itself :)
I edited the answer

Answer (score -1):

PaymentSplitter is a good abstract to use, but you must also consider Rarible's and OpenSea's royalty abstract. I suggest using all three.